# Many to many self reference table - guid Id changes itself

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have a many to many table that references. Itself it sounds crazy so here's an image for a better view of the problem
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj2zZ.png

I use guids as primary and foreign keys.
When I try to add a new instance of `Foo` to the database which has a relationship to some foo from the database, and on the exact moment when the line `myDbContext.Set<Foo>().Add(foo);` is passed, the Guid https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlFW9.png gets changed to https://i.stack.imgur.com/989nb.png

Code to create database:

```
 internal class Foo
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual List<DependencyFoo> Dependents { get; set; }
        public virtual List<DependencyFoo> DependentsOf { get; set; }
    }

   internal class DependencyFoo
    {
        public virtual Foo Dependent { get; set; }
        public Guid DependentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Foo DependentOf { get; set; }
        public Guid DependentOfId { get; set; }
    }

internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=fooDb;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DependencyFoo>()
              .HasKey(x => new { x.DependentOfId, x.DependentId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<DependencyFoo>()
                .HasOne(x => x.DependentOf)
                .WithMany(x => x.DependentsOf)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.DependentOfId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DependencyFoo>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Dependent)
                .WithMany(x => x.Dependents)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.DependentId);
        }
    }
```

Actual testing:

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDbContext myDbContext = new MyDbContext();
            myDbContext.Set<Foo>().Add(new Foo { Title = "Some cool title" });
            myDbContext.SaveChanges();

            Foo fooDb = myDbContext.Set<Foo>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == "Some cool title");
            DependencyFoo dependencyFoo = new DependencyFoo
            {
                DependentOfId = fooDb.Id
            };

            Foo foo = new Foo
            {
                DependentsOf = new List<DependencyFoo>()
            };
            foo.DependentsOf.Add(dependencyFoo);

            myDbContext.Set<Foo>().Add(foo);
        }
    }
```

Any idea why this is happening? Does it have to do something with my

relationship or ? PS (the example is simplified with foos :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with mappings `Foo.Dependents <-> DependencyFoo.Dependent` and `Foo.DependentsOf <-> DependencyFoo.DependentOf`.

The actual dependents/dependents of `foo` should really be something like (pseudocode):

```
IEnumerable<Foo> fooDependents = db.Set<DependencyFoo>()
    .Where(d => d.DependentOf.Id == foo.Id)
    .Select(d => d.Dependent);

IEnumerable<Foo> fooDependentsOf = db.Set<DependencyFoo>()
    .Where(d => d.Dependent.Id == foo.Id)
    .Select(d => d.DependentOf);
```

Note how the roles of collections in the main entity and reference navigation properties in the link entity are exchanged. To get the *dependents*, you have to select linked *dependent* filtered by *dependent **of***. And vice versa.

Currently you set `dependencyFoo.DependentOfId = fooDb.Id` and also `foo.DependentsOf.Add(dependencyFoo);`. Both they represents one and the same, so when you call add, the EF Core fixup generates new Guid for `for.Id` and assigns it to `dependencyFoo.DependentOfId`. At the same time, `dependencyFoo.Dependent` remains `null` and since `dependencyFoo.DependentId` value is `Guid.Empty`, EF Core creates and assigns a new Guid to it.

To fix the issue, simply exchange the collections in the fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DependencyFoo>()
    .HasOne(x => x.DependentOf)
    .WithMany(x => x.Dependents)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.DependentOfId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<DependencyFoo>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Dependent)
    .WithMany(x => x.DependentsOf)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.DependentId);
```

or alternatively (the effect is the same, I just find it easier to read and follow):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Dependents)
    .WithOne(x => x.DependentOf)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.DependentOfId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasMany(x => x.DependentsOf)
    .WithOne(x => x.Dependent)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.DependentId);
```

Comment: is this written anywhere in the docs? I can't find many docs/articles for self referencing tables, PS: I didn't have to make a migration, why is that?

Comment: Nope. But it's logical. Say you have `Person` with `Children` and `Parents` collections, and `PersonLink` class with `Parent` and `Child` references. Then the relationships are `Person.Children <-> PersonLink.Parent` and `Person.Parents <-> PersonLink.Child`

Comment: You don't need migration because exchanging the collection navigation properties does not change the link table FKs.